# How to add source information at bottom right corner of a figure in beamer?

Tags: beamer, macros

I am inserting several figures into my `beamer` presentation that I did not create myself. Therefore I would like to add some source information with just a command, e.g.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\newcommand{\credit}[1]{what to put here?}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{demo}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{demo}
\credit{Credit where credit is due.} % How best to implement this?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It should look something like this, though ideally the font would look not quite so bulky.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\newcommand{\credit}[1]{\par\hfill \footnotesize Credit:~\itshape#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{demo}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{demo}
\credit{where credit is due.} % How best to implement this?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great, thank you. I just changed `\footnotesize` to `\tiny`.

Answer (score 8):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{credit/.style={
  append after command={
    let \p1=($(\tikzlastnode.north east)-(\tikzlastnode.north west)$) in
      node[anchor=north east,align=right,text width=\x1,font=\footnotesize,
           node contents={Source:~\textit{#1}}, at = (\tikzlastnode.south east)]
    }
  }
}
\def\myimage#1#2#3{\tikz\node[inner sep=0,credit={#3}]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{demo}

\myimage{height=2cm}{demo}{where credit is due.}
\myimage{height=1cm,width=4cm}{demo}{Some longer test for testing and more words lack of imagination}

\myimage{height=2cm,width=\textwidth}{demo}{You get the idea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]